# Asynchronous threads not running in parallel under Spring Framework

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, asynchronous

I like to run two tasks undependent from each other. The problem is, that one of the task has a blocking part. As a result the second task is waiting for the first task. Because of that, I think both tasks are running on the same thread. But I like to run each task on a different thread with the aim, that each task don't have to wait for each other.

I have a configuration class AppConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig
{...
```

There I have defined two beans:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "watchFtp")
public FTPWatchScheduledTask ftpWatchScheduledTaskService()
{
    FTPWatchScheduledTask ftpWatchScheduledTask = new FTPWatchScheduledTaskService();
    return ftpWatchScheduledTask;
}
```

and

```
@Bean(initMethod = "watch")
public FileWatch fileWatchService()
{
    ...
    return fileWatchService;
}
```

Further the AppConfig is registered by the context:

```
public class FileSyncApplicationInitializer
implements WebApplicationInitializer
```

{

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(FileSyncApplicationInitializer.class);

private static AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container)
{
    // Create the Spring application context
    log.debug("Initializing file synchronisation ...");
    context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(AppConfig.class);

    log.debug("Contexts initialized ...");
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
        container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
```

Both defined init-Methods of each bean are annotated with "@Async":

```
@Async
public void watch() throws IOException
{
    WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    WatchKey key = temporaryDir.register(watcher,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);

    for (; ; )
    {
        try
        {
            key = watcher.take(); // take is waiting
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> pollEvent : key.pollEvents())
        {
            WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = pollEvent.kind();

            if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE)
            {
                WatchEvent<Path> event = (WatchEvent<Path>)pollEvent;
                Path fileName = (Path)key.watchable();
                Path fullPath = fileName.resolve(event.context());
                orderImportService.persistOrderXml(fileName);
                log.info("something was persisted");
            }

        }

        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Second init-method:

```
@Async
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void watchFtp()
{
    log.info(String.format("test time: " + dateFormat.format(new Date())));
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `watch()`? Why is `watchFtp` annotated with both `@Async` and `@Scheduled`?

Comment: Have you configured a `TaskExecutor`? It also looks like you are doing some file polling, why not use Spring Integration for that saves you writing your own infrastructure code.